# After assassinating the German ambassador, why did Vatan and "Beauséjour" shoot the walls, before neutralizing armed Nazis in front of them?

Tags: plot-explanation, allied

[Shooting the walls first](https://youtu.be/ntKYG1LdbV8?t=59) appears silly, before eliminating the armed Nazis in the reception like

1. [Hauptsturmführer Hobar](https://deutschesoldaten.fandom.com/wiki/Hobar),
2. and the husband in the white suit of the woman in red dress,

who both had enough time to aim pistols at Vatan and  "Beauséjour".

I am writing "Beauséjour" with quotation marks, because I forgot this German spy's true name.

Comment: One theory I heard was to make it look like indiscriminate shooting instead of an assassination, but presumably the witnesses would counter that - though it does lead into my own thoughts: shoot above the heads of those not being targeted, to keep them down on the ground and usually not looking at what's going on, then shoot the walls so the initial investigation would presume not an assassination and the lack of witnesses (because they kept their heads to the ground) would not be able to say otherwise. Clearly deliberate as they were fine with shooting those they needed to.